# Compile Program for MapReduce2 but still get JobTracker Error

Tags: hadoop2

I am trying to run a MapReduce 2 job on hadoop but get an error about connecting to port 8021. As far as I know this port is for the JobTracker, which is not used in MR2. This makes me wonder if I am somehow accidentally using MR1. However, extensive web search did not get me anywhere.

I used the new API (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*) and compiled with javac -cp 'yarn classpath' sourcefolder. Does anyone have a clue what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: which error do you get? Please add it to qour question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your configuration files and also make sure that your job tracker and task tracker are active. If its having problem connecting to port 8021, it might be used by other applications.